# Content security policy error in MV3 chrome extension

Tags: chrome-extension-manifest-v3

i'm trying to migrate a CE from manifest V2 to manifest V3. in my extension i have used the CSP the content_security_policy. in the guide they said that now the CSP is an abject instead of a string and i changed based on the documentation but i still have the same error.
this is my V2

```
{
  "name": "Mini Compass Data Lake",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "browser_action": {
      "default_popup": "index.html",
      "default_icon": "datalake32.png"
     
  },
  "icons":{
    "16": "datalake16.png",
    "32": "datalake32.png",
    "48": "datalake48.png",
    "128": "datalake128.png"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["app/background.js"]
},
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'sha256-MLFsIf1SpPWeg69jaAVLve0caDySR5tvthPAdm6eK8Q='; object-src 'self'",
  "permissions":["https://*/*"]
}
```

and this is the V3

```
{
        "name": "Mini Compass Data Lake",
        "version": "1.0",
        "manifest_version": 3,
        "action": {
                "default_popup": "index.html",
                "default_icon": "datalake32.png"
        },
        "icons": {
                "16": "datalake16.png",
                "32": "datalake32.png",
                "48": "datalake48.png",
                "128": "datalake128.png"
        },
        "background": {
                "service_worker": "app/background.js"
        },
        "content_security_policy": {
                "extension_pages": "script-src 'self' 'sha256-MLFsIf1SpPWeg69jaAVLve0caDySR5tvthPAdm6eK8Q='; object-src 'self'"
        },
        "host_permissions": [
                "https://*/*"
        ]
}
```

this is the error code i got

[image]

Comment: MV3 doesn't allow inline code, you can't relax its built-in CSP.

Comment: so for CE using CSP in MV2 there is no solution to migrate in MV3? thanks